# Is it possible to use Django's testing framework without having CREATE DATABASE rights?

Tags: django, postgresql

Since I don't have a hundred bazillion dollars, my Django app lives on a shared host, where [all kinds of crazy rules are in effect](http://dpaste.com/hold/196057/). Fortunately, they gave me shell access, which has allowed me to kick butts and take names. However I can't do anything about not having `CREATE DATABASE` rights.

I'm using postgresql and have a killer test suite, but am unable to run it due to the code not being able to create a new database. However I *am* able to create said database beforehand via cPanel and use it with Django. I just don't have `CREATE DATABASE` rights.

Is there a way I can still run my test suite?

Comment: Why don't you test your application on your computer?

Comment: It passes all the tests on my computer. The same is not true for the production environment. And that's what tests are good for - catching those kind of things.

Comment: then make your development environment more like your production environment.

Comment: Consider using virtual environment.  Still a good question, but virtual environment has been one of the best things I've added to my toolbox over the last year.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe workaround this using `sqlite3` engine to create a SQLite database. You can even create it in memory and drastically improve tests runtime.

To set it up just edit your database settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
        ... # other settings (HOST, USER etc.)
    },
}
```

Comment: I agree that using sqlite might be an acceptable workaround, but shared hosts typically have limited memory, so loading the entire test suite DB into memory might not be a good idea.

Comment: @Chris but you can still use sqlite on your file system, memory database is just a speed boost.

Comment: This is a great idea, and I tried this, and it worked with most of my tests, but then it crashed, I'm guessing due to memory like Chris said.